# Moving AJAX call from IIS6 to IIS7.5, fails on System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule.OnPostAcquireRequestState

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis-7.5

I am making an AJAX call to a WebMethod under IIS6 on Win2003Srv like this and it works fine:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Sub EmailManagers()
    'code
End Sub
```

with the AJAX call like this:

```
    function EmailManagers_Click() {
        alert('staring email send');
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                //url: "EACApprovalOverview.aspx/EmailManagers(" + document.URL + ")",
                url: "EACApprovalOverview.aspx/EmailManagers",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert("Emails Sent!");
                },
                fail: function (msg) {
                    alert("Email Send Failed!");
                }
            });
        alert('end email send');
        return false;
    };
```

When I run this app under IIS7.5 on Win2008Srv, I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".  Here's the stack trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule.OnPostAcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) +162
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +68
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Other errors I'm seeing in postings here contain an additional line at the top of the stack trace, like this:

```
   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceData.GetMethodData(String methodName)
   at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule.OnPostAcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Since i'm not getting to the WebServiceData.GetMethodData call, i'm guessing the System.Web.Handlers is not being loaded correctly, resulting in the ScriptModule being null.

I've got this in my web.config:

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</httpModules>
```

and i've ensured that .net 3.5 sp1 is installed.  I even checked the GAC and the dll is there.  What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 2):

After implementing a new page method in a new aspx, the NullReferenceException in 
OnPostAcquireRequestState happened here as well. It only happened on live servers but not on the development server.

Problem was the the live server was updated by copying only the bin directory from a precompiled Web Deployment Project. Because the site was precompiled and a wildcard handler, the aspx showed up fine without the aspx physically present.

But invoking page methods require the aspx to be present, so the page method worked again after simply copying the precompiled placeholder aspx into the live server.

Comment: Dude, the same happened with my colleague today. Thanks for posting. In a hurry, he actually uploaded only the precompiled bin and forgot to upload the aspx pages for the newly created forms. Now resolved. He spent almost a day on that :(  Thanks...